# How do I integrate the two different backend frameworks?

Tags: php, vue.js, flask

So I was given a half completed website from a friend to help complete for his start up. The issue is, that I don't know PHP and the other developer left and went ghost on the project! I'm left stuck with following behind with the work. I find the php system janky, therefore I redeveloped another piece of the site using Vue.JS and Flask. I deployed the vue.js frontend using google's Firebase, and Flask on pythonanywhere. However, the mainsite is hosted on Linode, which is a platform I'm also not familiar with. I'm trying to figure out, how to I append what I did to the main site (that's programmed in PHP, and SQL Database) just for long enough to fully redevelop the site in Vue.js and flask?

So currently, I have downloaded the entire files from their git repository, and I basically navigate through and had a friend helped me remove so many redundancies and bugs on their site. I wasn't conformable with the language, so I redeveloped a piece of the site with Vue.JS for the frontend and deployed the frontend on firebase and Flask python to serve as the backend and using SQLAlchemy databasing, that's running on pythonanywhere.

This is a snippet on how I'm calling to the flask api

```
       async setAuthenticated(login_status, user_data) {
      // Update the states
      this.logged_user_id = user_data.id;
      this.logged_user_username = user_data.username;
      this.authenticated = login_status;
      this.token = user_data.token;

      // Initialize Pusher JavaScript library
      pusher = new Pusher(process.env.VUE_APP_PUSHER_KEY, {
        cluster: process.env.VUE_APP_PUSHER_CLUSTER,
        authEndpoint: "https://theApiFrom.pythonanywhere/api/pusher/auth",
        auth: {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + this.token
          }
        }
      });

      // Get all the users from the server
      const users = await this.axios.get("https://theApiFrom.pythonanywhere.com/api/users", {
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + this.token }
      });

      // Get all users excluding the current logged user
      this.users = users.data.filter(
        user => user.userName != user_data.username
      );

      var notifications = pusher.subscribe(
        `private-notification_user_${this.logged_user_id}`
      );

      notifications.bind("new_chat", data => {
        const isSubscribed = pusher.channel(data.channel_name);
        if (!isSubscribed) {
          const one_on_one_chat = pusher.subscribe(data.channel_name);

          this.$set(this.messages, data.channel_name, []);

          one_on_one_chat.bind("new_message", data => {
            // Check if the current chat channel is where the message is comming from
            if (
              data.channel !== this.current_chat_channel &&
              data.from_user !== this.logged_user_id
            ) {
              // Get the index of the user that sent the message
              const index = this.users.findIndex(
                user => user.id == data.from_user
              );
              // Set the has_new_message status of the user to true
              this.$set(this.users, index, {
                ...this.users[index],
                has_new_message: true
              });
            }

            this.messages[data.channel].push({
              message: data.message,
              sentiment: data.sentiment,
              from_user: data.from_user,
              to_user: data.to_user,
              channel: data.channel
            });
          });
        }
      });
    },
    getMessage: function(channel_name) {
      this.axios
        .get(`https://theApiFrom.pythonanywhere/api/get_msg/${channel_name}`, {
          headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + this.token }
        })
        .then(response => {
          this.$set(this.messages, channel_name, response.data);
        });
    },

    chat: function(id) {
      this.active_chat_id = id;

      // Get index of the current chatting user...
      this.active_chat_index = this.users.findIndex(
        user => user.id == this.active_chat_id
      );

      // Set the has_new_message status of the user to true
      this.$set(this.users, this.active_chat_index, {
        ...this.users[this.active_chat_index],
        has_new_message: false
      });

      this.axios
        .post(
          "https://theApiFrom.pythonanywhere/api/request_chat",
          {
            from_user: this.logged_user_id,
            to_user: this.active_chat_id
          },
          { headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + this.token } }
        )
        .then(response => {
          this.users[this.active_chat_index]["channel_name"] =
            response.data.channel_name;

          this.current_chat_channel = response.data.channel_name;

          // Get messages on this channel
          this.getMessage(response.data.channel_name);

          var isSubscribed = pusher.channel(response.data.channel_name);

          if (!isSubscribed) {
            var channel = pusher.subscribe(response.data.channel_name);

            this.$set(this.messages, response.data.channel_name, []);

            channel.bind("new_message", data => {
              //Check if the current chat channel is where the message is comming from
              if (
                data.channel !== this.current_chat_channel &&
                data.from_user !== this.logged_user_id
              ) {
                // Set the has_new_message status of the user to true
                this.$set(this.users, this.active_chat_index, {
                  ...this.users[this.active_chat_index],
                  has_new_message: true
                });
              }

              this.messages[response.data.channel_name].push({
                message: data.message,
                sentiment: data.sentiment,
                from_user: data.from_user,
                to_user: data.to_user,
                channel: data.channel
              });
            });
          }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
    send_message: function(message) {
      this.axios.post(
        "https://theApiFrom.pythonanywhere/api/send_msg",
        {
          from_user: this.logged_user_id,
          to_user: this.active_chat_id,
          message: message,
          channel: this.current_chat_channel
        },
        { headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + this.token } }
      );
    }
```

The goal I'm trying to do, is add what I created into the mainsite files so that I can configure the domain name to be under the live site, so that people can navigate to my additional functionalities on the main site. I'm mainly focused on getting the Vue.js (client side) files onto the mainsite files  because I have webhooks pointed to the python side where the frontend part will call to.

Answer (score 1):

try use Apache virtual host.

run each site "php" and "flask" on different ports

then use apache vhost to point the localhost/php and localhost/flask to localhost:ports

example:

- localhost:8000 <- localhost/php
- localhost:8080 <- localhost/flask

Comment: Is this the link that you are referring too [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/)